# How to remove a single line from history?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-history

I'm working in Mac OSX, so I guess I'm using bash...?

Sometimes I enter something that I don't want to be remembered in the history. How do I remove it?

Comment: Very similar: [Is there any way to keep a command from being added to your history?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6094/is-there-any-way-to-keep-a-command-from-being-added-to-your-history)

Comment: `history -d <line_number>` didn't work for me, so just deleted the desired line and the one preceding it (that should start with `#`) from `~/.bash_history`.

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236094/how-to-remove-the-last-command-or-current-command-for-bonus-from-zsh-history

Comment: From `macOS Catalina` on, the standard shell is `zsh` and not `bash` and the `history` command works differently, so `history -d <line>` will not work. @toraritte answer becomes then: type  `vim .zsh_history` and delete typing `d` once on the line you need to delete. To save and quit then type `:x` and hit `Enter`.

Answer (score 651, accepted):

## Preventative measures

If you want to run a command without saving it in history, prepend it with an extra space

```
prompt$ echo saved
prompt$  echo not saved \
> #     ^ extra space
```

For this to work you need either `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth` in `HISTCONTROL`.  For example, run

```
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
```

To make this setting persistent, put it in your `.bashrc`.

## Post-mortem clean-up

If you've already run the command, and want to remove it from history, first use

```
history
```

to display the list of commands in your history.  Find the number next to the one you want to delete (e.g. 1234) and run

```
history -d 1234
```

Additionally, if the line you want to delete has already been written to your $HISTFILE (which typically happens when you end a session by default), you will need to write back to $HISTFILE, or the line will reappear when you open a new session:

```
history -w
```

Comment: It worked. I think we need to source ~/.bashrc after modifying it...

Comment: @BSeven Yes, all `bash` settings are stored in RAM while the shell is running.  The `rc` files are only for storing persistent settings for the next time the shell starts.

Comment: There are edge cases when this will not work, but under default configurations it should.

Comment: @jordanm What edge cases are you talking about?  Are they worth listing here?

Comment: @jw013 I set PROMPT_COMMAND to `history -a`, in that case it is already written to the history file, rather than on exit under normal configuration. Specifically: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/088

Comment: but I don't want history -d command itself to be logged into history??

Comment: What about clearing the current terminal window buffer? For example, if I run `history` to find the command in which I typed a secret command, I can use `history -d` to delete it but someone could simply scroll up my screen and see it.

Comment: @RohailAbbas - easy, you first enter `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace`, then invoke two `history -d` commands with a leading space - one for deleting your original command and one for deleting the ignorespace assignment.

Comment: YMMV, but here's how I cleared all entries that match a grep: `while true; do str=\`history | grep -m 1 YOUR_GREP_HERE | awk '{print $1}'\`; if [[ ! $str ]]; then break; fi; history -d $str; done`

Comment: `history -w ` does not exist oh RHEL 7 the reason why the commands still appear for zsh users is that you also have to delete the entry from .zsh_history AND very important to logout and login again.

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: Is it also possible to remove searching command from history, where when we do backward search via `ctrl-p` it shows up even it is not saved in the history @jw013

Comment: Why doesn't my `man history` show anything about `-d`, yet it worked? GNU History 8.1, 2020 July 17.

Comment: @Gauthier because `history` is also a bash builtin. `type history` reveals that. Use `man bash-builtins` to find the man page for it.

Comment: I get different line numbers at each call and they are always "out of range".
`196994  2024-01-25-23:17I inadvertently typed my password instead of "su"`
`196995  2024-01-25-23:17history`
`alex@Freesia:~$ history -d 196994`
`bash: history: 196994: history position out of range``

Comment: The `history -d <line number>` behaved strangely for me because of my PROMPT_COMMAND:
`export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a;history -r"`
Setting `PROMPT_COMMAND= ` in a terminal before calling `history -d <line number>` did the trick.
Beware however that you cannot delete several entries in one command and that line numbers change after you have deleted an entry.

Answer (score 94):

1. To clear all your history, use

   ```
   history -c
   ```
2. To delete a single line, use

   ```
   history -d linenumber
   ```

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: This could definitely use an explanation of what "line number" is and how to find it.

Comment: Note that you must start a new shell session in order for these changes to take effect.

Comment: @Clonkex the "line numbers" for each past command will be visible when running `history`

Comment: @DavidSawyer I see, this answer would make sense to someone familiar with `history`. I'm not familiar with it, as you can maybe tell.

Answer (score 17):

### Zsh on Mac

If you are using Zsh, `history -d linenumber` doesn't work to delete a specific line number in the command line history. However you can edit the history file. Close and reopen your terminal and edit the history like so:

```
nano ~/.zsh_history
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626501/3681880) for more details.

Comment: Same for tcsh. you can edit ~/.history

Answer (score 14):

I have this in my `~/.bashrc`, which makes the command `$ forget` delete the previous command from history

```
function forget() {                                                              
   history -d $(expr $(history | tail -n 1 | grep -oP '^\s*\d+') - 1);              
}
```

Comment: That seems a little complicated. Wouldn't `history -d $( history | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d " " )` be simpler?

Comment: `history | tail -n1` is the `history` command itself, so deleting that number gets the wrong entry. However, `history -d $( history | awk 'END{print $1-1}' )` combines the line select, field select, and subtraction.

Comment: Any chance someone could help out with portin this to zshell?

Answer (score 11):

You always can edit and remove entries from `~/.bash_history`, useful when you want to remove either one entry or more than one entry

Comment: Most likely these entries will be reintroduced when you exit the shell.

Comment: This may needlessly remove more than necessary, or may possibly not remove anything, depending on how the shell is configured.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to forget the entire bash session, you can `kill` the current bash process. Since the variable `$$` hold the `pid` of the current shell, you can do:

```
kill -9 $$
```

Comment: This does not take the history that is written to `$HISTFILE` into account.

Comment: @Kusalananda unless you have [taken special steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/673283/146273) to write to the `$HISTFILE` immediately, this should work. The ONLY think I have taken into account is the `$HISTFILE`. What experience have you had (with my proposal) that causes you concern?

Comment: If the thing that the user entered was in a previous session, killing the current shell would not remove that single thing from the history file.  Also, I'm on systems where the admins have changed the default setup so that commands are written to the history file after every given command. We know nothing about the current user's setup.

Comment: @Kusalananda your statement is true. However, I would hope that no one would ever try to kill the current process trying to affect the result of a past completed process. That's just illogical to expect. But it does suggest a slightly different phrasing to your original comment that would have avoided the confusion. "This does not *affect* the history that *was* written to $HISTFILE *in previous sessions*." In other words, "this concept is only good for preventing the situation, not correcting it." Thanks for clarifying, friend.

Comment: Well, it wouldn't affect the history written to `$HISTFILE` in the current session either, so I really don't see how that comment could be misinterpreted. The only thing you have to add to your answer is the assumptions under which the given solution solves the problem.  There is really only one assumption, namely that the command that should be removed from the history hasn't yet been written to `$HISTFILE`. Then you may want to elaborate under what conditions the command _would_ have been written to `$HISTFILE`.

Answer (score 5):

To remove a single line from the history file, use the -d option. For example, if you want to clear a command where you entered the clear-text password as in the scenario above, find the line number in the history file and run this command.

`$ history -d 2038`

To delete or clear all the entries from bash history, use the history command below with the -c option.

`$ history -c`

Alternatively, you can use the command below to delete the history of all last executed commands permanently in the file.

`$ cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history`

Also With Bash 5, you can delete a range aswell

`history -d 511-520`

Comment: history -d line number didnt work for me. I'm using mac.

Comment: You need to brew cask install jumpcut or else follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/17200/how-do-i-view-my-clipboard-history-on-os-x)

Answer (score 3):

1- in bash terminal type

`history` # This will list all commands in history .bash_history file with line numbers

ex:

```
  ...
  987  cd
  988  ssh x@127.0.0.1
  990  exit
  991  cd
```

2- pick the CMD line number you want to delete

`history -d 988`

Note: if you want to delete for example last 3 CMDs, just pick the third line number from bottom ex: 988 and repeat the CMD `history -d 988` 3 times in sequence.

Comment: Welcome on U&L! This really looks similar to (a part of) the accepted answer (except for the suggestion about deleting consecutive commands). Is there anything you can add to make it less of a repetition?

Comment: Sorry, no and for the first look I didn't understand the accepted answer [and you won't believe that I checked other answers with more details explained] so when I figured out that `history` command lists the used commands I just wanted to explain that!

Comment: No problem. Answers that happen to be duplicates of other answers may eventually be deleted and I just try to make sure people have room to deal with that possibility before it happens ;-)

Comment: Alternate opinion. The question asked to delete a single entry, so I upvoted the ones that answered the question first, not as an afterthought.

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the changes after you cleared the history. And if you wouldn't like to have the history wipe command in your history then you need to run the command like that:

`history -c && history -w && logout`

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu (but I'm pretty sure, it will be work for other Linux distributions and also MacOS the same way) the bash history file can be simply edited in an arbitrary text editor:

```
$ nano ~/.bash_history
```

If you don't know, where it's stored, you can find it as follows:

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
```

Or you can just do it a bit more generic way:

```
$ nano $HISTFILE
```

Comment: This does not take into account that the current in-memory history of the shell would be written to the file when the shell exits. This would not delete a command from the history that is resident in the in-memory history of the shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`hstr`](https://github.com/dvorka/hstr) (a way better `reverse-i-search` that can be installed with `sudo apt install hstr`), then it's really simple:

1. Open your terminal and press `Ctrl+r` to search your history.
2. Type some characters to search for the command you want to delete from your history, then use arrow keys to go down and highlight the item.
3. Press the `delete` key, and press `y` to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a range of history lines, you can use the script below.

This example will delete history output from line 1 to line 150.

```bsh
for i in `history | awk 'NR > 1 && NR <=150{print   $1}'`; do history -d $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick steps:

1. Find out where is your terminal's history file with `echo $HISTFILE`
2. Open the file with your text editor
3. Delete the sensitive lines you find there
4. Save the file
5. Close and reopen your terminal
6. **DONE**: your history is clean! You can validate that by running the `history` command in your terminal