# Don't save failed command to history?

Tags: command-line, zsh, command-history

I'm using snippet code below to exclude all failed commands (return code 1) from saving to zsh history:

```
 zshaddhistory() { whence ${${(z)1}[1]} >| /dev/null || return 1 }
```

But if the command is an alias `lsl` (alias lsl='ls -l') the failed command will still be inserted into zsh history:

```
lsl whatever_folder_doesnt_exist
```

`whatever_folder_doesnt_exist` doesn't exist and I observe `lsl whatever_folder_doesnt_exist` still in zsh history.

Here I want to exclude all command that return code is not `0`, how can I do that?

Comment: Uh? You aren't excluding failed commands, You're excluding commands that don't exist (assuming that the first word is the command name, which is not always true).

Comment: I don’t understand zsh syntax well, how to get the purpose?

Comment: Related: [How to make Zsh not store failed command](https://superuser.com/questions/902241)

Comment: @Devon I get code from link you paste.

Comment: What would you think about a `precmd` that checks the return code and ["manually" edits the history file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236261/117549) to remove failed commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `zsh-hist` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-hist) to set up a `precmd` hook that deletes the last item from history, if it had a non-zero exit status:

```bsh
source path/to/zsh-hist.plugin.zsh
delete-failed-history() {
  (( ? )) && 
    hist -s d -1
}
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd delete-failed-history
```

If you want that it deletes only commands that have exit status `1` exactly, then change `(( ? ))` to `(( ? == 1 ))`.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes it impossible to correct the command, since the failed command line can't be restored by pressing the up arrow anymore.

Comment: It’s possible to automatically load the faulty command into the command line, so you can fix it. That wasn’t what asked, though. If you want me to tell you how to do that, feel free to open a new question. 