# How to remove a single command from TCSH history?

Tags: shell, command-line, command-history, tcsh

I'm trying to remove a single command from TCSH history on RHEL 6, but couldn't find a way. I tried out the following Bash command as in [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49214/how-to-remove-a-single-line-from-history), it didn't work.

```
history -d <line_number>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: dang you `tcsh` and `csh`. a thousand curses upon thee.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use tcsh, but perusing the man page suggests:

1. save current history with `history -S`
2. edit the history file to remove the offending command with `vi ~/.history` (or `vi $histfile`, if you've overridden the default).
3. clear history with `history -c`
4. load revised history with `history -L`

Read your tcsh man page for the various details.

Comment: I opened a tcsh shell to test these commands; they worked as advertised.    
   `101  14:40   history -L
   102  14:39   echo command here
   104  14:39   history -S` -- where I manually edited out command #103 from ~/.history.

Comment: Those commands worked for me, I'm accepting your answer.