# Prevent ZSH from saving specific command

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Is there a way to Prevent ZSH from saving specific command in history. I dont want zsh to save `git clone //url` command.

Comment: `HISTORY_IGNORE="git clone"`. Check [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6094/414186)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` option.

```bash
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

From `man zshoptions`:

> HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
>
> > Remove command lines from the history list when the first character on
> > the line is a space, or when one of the expanded aliases contains a
> > leading space. Note that the command lingers in the internal history
> > until the next command is entered before it vanishes, allowing you to
> > briefly reuse or edit the line. If you want to make it vanish right
> > away without entering another command, type a space and press return.